# Nodejs app not authenticating properly with Google Cloud Storage Bucket?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, backend

Building an app user profile photo component. I set up a Google Cloud storage bucket without public access and using fine-grained ACLs, and a service acct with Storage Admin role. I downloaded JSON key, placed into root directory alongside package.json, and referenced in my file upload/download controller:

```
const processFile = require("../middleware/upload");
const { format } = require("util");
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const storage = new Storage({ keyFilename: "my-service-account.json" });
const bucket = storage.bucket("my-gcp-storage-bucket");


const upload = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await processFile(req, res);

        if (!req.file) {
            return res.status(400).send({ message: "Please upload a file!" });
        }

        const blob = bucket.file(req.file.originalname);
        const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
            resumable: false,
        });

        blobStream.on("error", (err) => {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
        });

        blobStream.on("finish", async (data) => {
            const publicUrl = format(
                `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`
            );

            try {
                await bucket.file(req.file.originalname).makePublic();
            } catch {
                return res.status(500).send({
                    message:
                        `Uploaded the file successfully: ${req.file.originalname}, but public access is denied!`,
                    url: publicUrl,
                });
            }

            res.status(200).send({
                message: "Uploaded the file successfully: " + req.file.originalname,
                url: publicUrl,
            });
        });

        blobStream.end(req.file.buffer);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);

        if (err.code == "LIMIT_FILE_SIZE") {
            return res.status(500).send({
                message: "File size cannot be larger than 2MB!",
            });
        }

        res.status(500).send({
            message: `Could not upload the file: ${req.file.originalname}. ${err}`,
        });
    }
};

const getListFiles = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const [files] = await bucket.getFiles();
        let fileInfos = [];

        files.forEach((file) => {
            fileInfos.push({
                name: file.name,
                url: file.metadata.mediaLink,
            });
        });

        res.status(200).send(fileInfos);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);

        res.status(500).send({
            message: "Unable to read list of files!",
        });
    }
};

const download = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const [metaData] = await bucket.file(req.params.name).getMetadata();
        res.redirect(metaData.mediaLink);

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: "Could not download the file. " + err,
        });
    }
};

module.exports = {
    upload,
    getListFiles,
    download,
};
```

I am able to upload into my bucket and list files - but I cannot download or see image previews in my React frontend. I get this message when trying to use the download API:

*Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).*

These specifically are what does not work:

```
const getListFiles = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const [files] = await bucket.getFiles();
        let fileInfos = [];

        files.forEach((file) => {
            fileInfos.push({
                name: file.name,
                url: file.metadata.mediaLink,
            });
        });

        res.status(200).send(fileInfos);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);

        res.status(500).send({
            message: "Unable to read list of files!",
        });
    }
};

const download = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const [metaData] = await bucket.file(req.params.name).getMetadata();
        res.redirect(metaData.mediaLink);

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: "Could not download the file. " + err,
        });
    }
};
```

I can't figure out what's wrong here, as I can upload and list files - just not download. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the service account has necessary permissions to download files .Refer to  this [document1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions#object_permissions) & [document2](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get#required-permissions) for more information.

> The authenticated user must have the storage.objects.get IAM
> permission to use this method. To return object ACLs, the
> authenticated user must also have the storage.objects.getIamPolicy
> permission.

Also  initialize  gcloud environment `gcloud init` then set up application default credentials by running `gcloud auth application-default login`.